# JSON load function for JSON FILE Python

Tags: python, json, python-3.x

I am quite new in Python. I have a JSON file in which I need to do some analytics.

When I load the file, I have many tracebacks.

The code is simple

```
with open('Dataset.json') as f:
    jsonData = json.load(f)
```

=======
Traceback is

```
   File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/json/__init__.py", line 296, in load
   parse_constant=parse_constant, object_pairs_hook=object_pairs_hook, **kw)
   File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/json/__init__.py", line 348, in loads
   return _default_decoder.decode(s)
   File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/json/decoder.py", line 340, in decode
   raise JSONDecodeError("Extra data", s, end)
   json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Extra data: line 2 column 1 (char 366)
```

How can I decode this ?

Thank you

Comment: Can you please add a sample of the json file `Dataset.json`? It seems like you have multiple json inside the file...

Comment: try this:   with open('Dataset.json') as f:
    jsonData = json.load(f)

Comment: example of code {"category": "WELLNESS", "headline": "Tracey Heggins, Senna Of The Twilight Saga, Shares Her GPS Guide", "authors": "", "link": "https://www.huffingtonpost.com/entry/tracey-heggins-gps-guide-senna_us_5b9c52d7e4b03a1dcc7dcd67", "short_description": "The stress and strains of our always-connected lives can sometimes take us off course. GPS For The Soul can help you find", "date": "2012-09-22"}

Comment: I need to Aggregate text data under “short_description” and “headline” and Use the aggregated text data to create two N-gram models for N = {1, 2}; after I need to write the two models to one EXCEL file in two different sheets;; any tips? Thanks

Comment: What is it that you don't understand in the error message ? It explicitely tells you 1/ that your file's content is not valid json, 2/ _why_ it's not valid json (there are additional data after the json object) and 3/ where those additional data start (at column 1 of line 2). The solution is plain simple: open the json file and check what you have in it. As toom501 already mentionned, I suspect you actually have more than one json object in your file, and probably one per line (which would make your file a "json-lines" one http://jsonlines.org/).

Comment: NB: you have to post a longer extract (copy-pasted) of the file (not one single line) for a proper MCVE...

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
import json

with open('Dataset.json', 'r') as f:
    jsonData = json.load(f)
```

This is assuming your dataset (json) is properly formatted. by looking at your error posted, I am thinking it maybe is not.

Comment: the default mode for `open` is read, so this shouldn't make a difference

Comment: I did not know that it had a default, THANKS

Comment: I did a loop to open every line and it worked; for line in f:
        data = json.loads(line)

Comment: {"category": "WELLNESS", "headline": "Tracey Heggins, Senna Of The Twilight Saga, Shares Her GPS Guide", "authors": "", "link": "https://www.huffingtonpost.com/entry/tracey-heggins-gps-guide-senna_us_5b9c52d7e4b03a1dcc7dcd67", "short_description": "The stress and strains of our always-connected lives can sometimes take us off course. GPS For The Soul can help you find", "date": "2012-09-22"}

Comment: I need to Aggregate text data under “short_description” and “headline” and Use the aggregated text data to create two N-gram models for N = {1, 2}; after I need to write the two models to one EXCEL file in two different sheets;; any tips? Thanks